# AngularJS - How to reload data in Custom directive

Tags: html, angularjs, directive

I have a custom directive..I need to reload the data up on a button click...fetching the data fresh from back-end service and refresh on the screen. can someone help me with getting through this ?

Comment: Can you provide your codes?

Comment: I'm going to flag this answer as "too broad" please post your code

Answer (score 0):

You can bind local scope/directive property to parent scope property. Here is a simple example that updates contents of directive on button click.

http://jsbin.com/dijijonedu/1/edit?html,js,output